# where to define a bound attribute in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to have an input text field be disabled by default and then be updatable to being able to be edited.

I have

```
{{input value=name disabled=entryNotAllowed }}  <br /> <button {{action "canEdit"}}>Contract</button>
```

but where do I define entryNotAllowed where I set it to true. I tried on the model, the route, and the controller but none of them seemed to work.

I thought the controller most likely so I added this:

```
Hex.MenuController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    entryNotAllowed: true
});
```

or in Route

```
Hex.MenuRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    entryNotAllowed: true,
    actions: {
        canEdit: function() {
```

but no dice. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of your template defaults to the controller, so you can define/modify `entryNotAllowed` from there.

### App

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  entryNotAllowed: true,
  actions: {
    canEdit: function() {
      this.set('entryNotAllowed', !this.get('entryNotAllowed'));
    }
  }
});
```

### Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{input value=name disabled=entryNotAllowed }}<br />
  <button {{action "canEdit"}}>Contract</button>
</script>
```

[JSBin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uVaGezES/1/edit)

Comment: thx, I realized that prob my problem is that I have a single object but it has many sub-objects. I'm not sure if ObjectController or ArrayControlller is more appropriate.